# Getting a link from another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have

```
<div class="box box1">
 <div class="content">

  <img a href="http://www.example.com" />
    <img src="https://www.google.ie/images/srpr/logo11w.png"</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is make the entire div of box clickable.

I have looked around here in StackOverFlow and seen some great examples but I have tried them and I could not get them to work.

For Example:

```
$div.next('div.box2').find('a').attr('href', $div.find('a').attr('href'));
```

Any help would be great on how to do this in jquery

Comment: What is `$div`? Your HTML is invalid by the way. You never closed the second `img` and an `img` doesn't have a `href` attribute but a `src`.

Comment: what u want on click ?

Comment: that is the content div div.content

Comment: In that case, `$div.next('div.box2')` won't find anything. Because there is no div with that class in your box.

Comment: WHen I click div box, it should link to a href="example" in div content

Comment: Thanks fixed it, More interested in the jquery statment more then the HTML, thats just a example from my main code that is alot more complicated like the generation of give with php and getting content from a framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".box").click(function(){
     window.location=$(".whereeveryourelookingfor").find("a").attr("href"); 
     return false;
});
```

you can make the mouse pointer also look like the one on href , use the following css

```
.box{ cursor:pointer; }
```

> http://jsfiddle.net/r9Xhf/

Comment: This looks solid, Giving it a go now

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="box box1" style="cursor: pointer">
<div class="content">
 <a href="example">
  <img a href="http://www.example.com" />
    <img src="https://www.google.ie/images/srpr/logo11w.png"</a>
</div></div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.box').click(function(){
    window.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
});
```